# Navigation2:[navfn_planner] Original error: GetCostmap service client: async_send_request failed

Tags: navigation, mapping, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS version: Dashing

I've launched the navigation2 on the physical robot

After I set the initial pose, both navfn_planner and map_server show some error

```
[navfn_planner-6] [ERROR] []: Caught exception in callback for transition 10
[navfn_planner-6] [ERROR] []: Original error: GetCostmap service client: async_send_request failed
[navfn_planner-6] [WARN] []: Error occurred while doing error handling.
[navfn_planner-6] [FATAL] [navfn_planner]: Lifecycle node entered error state
[lifecycle_manager-1] [ERROR] [lifecycle_manager]: Failed to change state for node: navfn_planner
[lifecycle_manager-1] [ERROR] [lifecycle_manager]: Failed to bring up node: navfn_planner, aborting bringup

[lifecycle_manager-1] [INFO] [lifecycle_manager]: Starting the system bringup...
[lifecycle_manager-1] [INFO] [lifecycle_manager]: Creating and initializing lifecycle service clients 
[world_model-4] [INFO] [global_costmap.global_costmap_rclcpp_node]: [signalFailure] Drop message: frame 'laser' at time 1637655781.765 for reason(0)
[lifecycle_manager-1] [INFO] [lifecycle_manager]: Configuring and activating map_server
[map_server-2] [WARN] [rcl_lifecycle]: No transition matching 1 found for current state active
[map_server-2] [ERROR] []: Unable to start transition 1 from current state active: Transition is not registered., at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-dashing-rcl-lifecycle-0.7.10/src/rcl_lifecycle.c:327
[lifecycle_manager-1] [ERROR] [lifecycle_manager]: Failed to change state for node: map_server
[lifecycle_manager-1] [ERROR] [lifecycle_manager]: Failed to bring up node: map_server, aborting bringup
```

[image: image description]

And I have no idea what is going on

Here is my config file

```
amcl:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: false
    alpha1: 0.2
    alpha2: 0.2
    alpha3: 0.2
    alpha4: 0.2
    alpha5: 0.2
    base_frame_id: "base_footprint"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.5
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    lambda_short: 0.1
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
    laser_max_range: 100.0
    laser_min_range: -1.0
    laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
    max_beams: 60
    max_particles: 2000
    min_particles: 500
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    pf_err: 0.05
    pf_z: 0.99
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 1
    robot_model_type: "differential"
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    sigma_hit: 0.2
    tf_broadcast: true
    transform_tolerance: 1.0
    update_min_a: 0.2
    update_min_d: 0.25
    z_hit: 0.5
    z_max: 0.05
    z_rand: 0.5
    z_short: 0.05

amcl_map_client:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: false

amcl_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: false

bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: false
    bt_xml_filename: "navigate_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml"


dwb_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: false
    debug_trajectory_details: True
    min_vel_x: 0.0
    min_vel_y: 0.0
    max_vel_x: 0.26
    max_vel_y: 0.0
    max_vel_theta: 1.0
    min_speed_xy: 0.0
    max_speed_xy: 0.26
    min_speed_theta: 0.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    # Add high threshold velocity for turtlebot 3 issue.
    # https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/issues/75
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    acc_lim_x: 2.5
    acc_lim_y: 0.0
    acc_lim_theta: 3.2
    decel_lim_x: -2.5
    decel_lim_y: 0.0
    decel_lim_theta: -3.2
    vx_samples: 20
    vy_samples: 5
    vtheta_samples: 20
    sim_time: 1.7
    linear_granularity: 0.05
    xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
    transform_tolerance: 0.2
    critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "BaseObstacle", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist"]
    BaseObstacle.scale: 0.02
    PathAlign.scale: 0.0
    GoalAlign.scale: 0.0
    PathDist.scale: 32.0
    GoalDist.scale: 24.0
    RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0


local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: false
      global_frame: odom
      plugin_names: ["obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      plugin_types: ["nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer", "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"]
      rolling_window: true
      width: 3
      height: 3
      resolution: 0.05
      robot_radius: 0.105
      inflation_layer.cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
      obstacle_layer:
        enabled: True
      always_send_full_costmap: True
      observation_sources: scan
      scan:
        topic: /scan
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        clearing: True
        marking: True
  local_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: false
  local_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: false

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: false
      robot_radius: 0.105
      obstacle_layer:
        enabled: True
      always_send_full_costmap: True
      observation_sources: scan
      scan:
        topic: /scan
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        clearing: True
        marking: True
  global_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: false
  global_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: false

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: false
    yaml_filename: "test_ros_map.yaml"

lifecycle_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: false
    autostart: True
    node_names: ['map_server', 'amcl',
                 'world_model', 'dwb_controller',
                 'navfn_planner', 'bt_navigator']

lifecycle_manager_service_client:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: false

lifecycle_manager_client_service_client:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: false

navfn_planner:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: false
    tolerance: 1.0
    use_astar: True

navfn_planner_GetCostmap_client:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: false

robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: false

world_model:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: false
```

Any help would be very appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391478/navigation2:%5Bnavfn_planner%5D-original-error:-getcostmap-service-client:-async_send_request-failed/) by [JonyK](https://answers.ros.org/users/72345/jonyk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2021-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dashing has been long since EOLed https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Releases.html. As the maintainer of Nav2, we're not maintaining Dashing anymore and I'm sure there are more quirky bugs like that you'll run into due to the general instability that was present in the stack at that time. I highly suggest you upgrade to a more recent distribution.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JonyK](https://answers.ros.org/users/72345/jonyk/) on 2021-11-24**:
OK. Thanks